# Maximum Sub-Set Sum

Tags: algorithm, subset-sum

I'm trying to solve a slightly different variation of the Maximum Sub-Set Sum problem. Instead of consecutive elements, I want to find the elements that gives you the largest sum in the array. For example, given the following array:

{1,-3,-5,3,2,-7,1} the output should be 7 ( the sub-array with largest sum is {1,3,2,1} ).

Here the code I use to calculate the max sum:

```
    int max(int a, int b)
    {
        if (a >= b)

            return a;

        return b;
    }

    int func(List<Integer> l, int idx, int sum)
    {
        if (idx < 0)

            return sum;

        return max ( func(l,idx - 1, sum+l.get(idx)), func(l,idx-1,sum) );

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> l = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        l.add(-2);
        l.add(-1);
        l.add(-3);
        l.add(-4);
        l.add(-1);
        l.add(-2);
        l.add(-1);
        l.add(-5);
        System.out.println(func(l,l.size()-1,0));
    }
```

It works when I use positive and negative numbers together in the same array. However, the problem starts when I use only negative numbers - the output always is 0. I guess it happens because I send 0 as the sum at the very first time when I call the function. Can someone tell me how should I change my function so it will work with only negative numbers as well.

Comment: Your task does not make sense. It will be always a an array of all positive elements from your original array.  No need for any calculations.

Comment: If it's all positive then you're are right. But when it has negative and positive together - then you need to calculate.

Comment: No, you do not. It will **always** be - all positive numbers, assuming there is at least one.

Comment: I see what you mean, you are right! Thanks for pointing it !

Comment: In order to make it algorithm-worthy you need a constraint.  That's what "*consecutive numbers*" requirement was for.

Comment: The problem could be equivalently worded as "find the sum of the subset containing all positive integers of the input". Which obviously leads to the answer 0 / empty subset, if only negative parameters are input. The major issue with your code is the non-polynomial runtime of `O(n^2)`, which is simply a waste of computational power. Most important question: why would 0 be an incorrect output in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is unnecessarily complicated and inefficient (it has an `O(2^n)` time complexity).

Here's a simple and efficient (`O(N)` time, `O(1)` extra space) way to do it:

1. If there's at least one non-negative number in the list, return the sum of all positive numbers.
2. Return the largest element in the list otherwise.

Here's some code:

```
def get_max_non_empty_subset_sum(xs):
     max_elem = max(xs)
     if max_elem < 0:
          return max_elem
     return sum(x for x in xs if x > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The special case would be when all elements are negative. In this case find the least negative number. That would be your answer. This can be done in O(N) time complexity.

**PSEUDO CODE**

```
ALLNEG=true
LEAST_NEG= -INFINITY
for number in list:
    if number>=0
        ALLNEG=false
        break
    else if number>LEAST_NEG
        LEAST_NEG=number
if ALLNEG==true
    answer=LEAST_NEG
else
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think about this approach.

Comment: Though your question might be slightly incorrectly framed. I think you are looking for maximum subset sum . Sub array means contiguous elements only.

Comment: What do you mean by `answer=LEAST_NEG`?

Comment: @PM77-1 The special case in this problem is when all numbers in the list are negative. In this case the answer will be the least negative number. LEAST_NEG holds the value of that number, provided that all numbers in the list are negative.

Comment: @PM77-1 , the variable answer is the required solution. If all numbers are negative, the least negative number is the answer.

Comment: No, if all numbers are negative - then the minimum of all numbers is the answer.  For {-1; -2} the answer is {-1}.

Comment: @PM77-1 by least negative , I mean the number closest to 0.

Comment: In your example the minimum is actually -2, if all the numbers are negative, then the solution should be the maximum number - the least negative one.

Comment: @Keselme  I hope you understand the solution. To the best of my knowledge it is correct.

Comment: `LEAST_NEG= -INFINITY` - does it mean closest to 0?

Comment: @PM77-1 That is the initial value to ensure that when we are inside the loops, the if conditions make LEAST_NEG the minimum value. This will not happen if it is initialized with 0.

Comment: It is a PSEUDOCODE @PM77-1

Comment: @Dukeling the question just asked about the special case of all negative numbers.

Comment: I see what you mean now. You may want to expand your answer a bit.